# How can I get rendering progress information through maxcript?

Tags: rendering, maxscript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQzPW.png)

How can I get rendering progress information through maxcript?
I have a job that needs to get the rendering progress information through maxscript, compile the dll and can't get useful things. I hope to get help.

Answer (score 0):

The maxscript `render()` function has `progressbar:` parameter to display progress.

If you are rendering frames, you can set up a separate thread which checks for number of files saved using a timer.

If it is a net render then there is an interface to get render info. See here:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_DEF2CDBF_C729_46B9_BC0D_F030E255E3A7_htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Sorry, maybe it’s not clear to me.
I now have a separate thread. When I execute max quick render, my independent thread will get the current rendering progress information. Now there is no correct command to get it. Help with “progressCB.setTitle” can change him but can't get it

Comment: Depends on where you are trying to show the information on rendered files.The main UI will be locked up while it renders, so it cannot be shown there. Perhaps render in a separate thread and update the main UI. However, I am only guessing this. I never tested render() in a thread in maxscript.

Answer (score 0):

Try the callbacks #pre/postRenderFrame
http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_C1F6495F_5831_4FC8_A00C_667C5F2EAE36_htm